# How to harmonize unpredictable playback speeds in animated Sticker Pack Application?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, optimization

**EDIT:** I've run more tests with interesting results, the updates listed in the table below.

It seems if I set the number of **frames** and **frame rate** of the APNG to **16**, **32**, **48** or **64**, the Sticker Pack Application plays animations at the intended speed in Messages and everything looks right.

***But why exactly?*** I can't seem to explain it.

Could this be due to 64-bit processing? A secret quirk in iOS or Messages? Or something else?

> **Question**
>
> What's going on here with animated sticker playback?
>
> I've read through the details on the developer website but there
>   doesn't appear to be any solid technical details available for
>   Sticker Pack Applications and frame rate limitations.
>
> - Why are animated stickers not playing at the intended speed in Messages on device?
> - Why do stickers with 30, 45, and 60 frames play slower?
> - How can I ensure Messages always plays sticker packs at the intended and correct speed?
> - What are frame rate limitations of Sticker Pack Applications?

---

**Background**

I'm experimenting in Xcode with a Sticker Pack Application, creating an animated sticker pack. However, the sticker packs created result in unpredictable animation playback speeds depending on the number of frames used.

Messages on the iOS simulator doesn't display the animated sticker pack well, and Messages on Mac also gives unpredictable playback results, so I'm testing on device, iPad mini (A7 processor, M7 motion coprocessor), running iOS 10.2.1.

(Clearly the aim is to use the least amount of frames to reduce the load on the system and preserve battery. However some animations require a high frame rate to get smooth fluid playback, for instance, animations with frame images that have high contrast and a lot of visual motion.)

---

**Tests**

I have used Animated PNG (APNG) files. I have four APNG file variants including 15, 30, 45 and 60 frames per second (FPS). The duration of a complete animation cycle is 1 second for each file. The animation is repeated forever.

(Initially I tried individual Image Sequences and have Xcode compile them, but these were even less predictable, created larger file sizes, slow to load multiple stickers on device and caused Xcode to hang as the number of stickers increased in the project.)

---

**Results**

In the table below, animations with a frame rate of 30 and 45 play 1.5x slower, while an animation with a frame rate of 60 plays 2x slower. I would have expected that all animations would play the same duration.

(When loading a single Image Sequence in Xcode instead of an APNG, a 60 frame animation plays correctly, but due to the large Xcode compiled file size, the sticker crashes when being used.)

---

***Table.*** APNG tests, 15, 30, 45 and 60 frame rates. Update: APNG 16, 32, 48 and 64 frame rates.

[image]

Comment: I assume you are using a `MSStickerView` as the only subview. Is this right?

Comment: This is a Sticker Pack Application, it isn't the similar but different iMessage Application. Hope that helps clarify.